# Html2canvas show scrollbar of a div element with onrendered function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, html2canvas

So what I did was use the Html2canvas library to capture my DOM and create a canvas "image" from it. Now i wanted to test it on elements with scrollbars themselves, such as a div with text.

Here you can see how it looks on my (test) website:

[image]

I've set the width and height of the div too small, with overflow: scroll. Now here is how it looks like when it's rendered:

[image]

Is there a way for Html2canvas to load the scrollbar? Is there another way for me to 'solve' this issue with something so that scrollbars show up when rendered?

Comment: scrollbars depend on the browser/OS, so no.

Comment: Mhm, that's a bummer ... Oh thank you for the response.